How to make styled-components work with Astro ? __vite_ssr_import_0__.default.div is not a function when using styled-components in Astro project
19:54:29 [ERROR] vite_ssr_import_0.default.div is not a function
Stack trace:
at C:\Users\prash\OneDrive\Desktop\tac-website\src\styles\Header.js:3:42
[...] See full stack trace in the browser, or rerun with --verbose.
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Verified that all dependencies are correctly installed.
Ensured that the astro.config.mjs file includes the React integration.
Cleared the node_modules directory and reinstalled dependencies.

Despite these efforts, the same error persists. I expected the styled component to render correctly within my Astro project, but it seems like there's an issue with how styled-components is being imported or used.
What additional context or details should others know about?
Node.js version: 18.3.1
Operating System: Windows`

any update here or any workaround?

The error mentions the issue is in a file in your project called 'tac-website\src\styles\Header.js on line 3.
But, based on how how high up the error is on your file, I'm guessing there could be an issue with how you are importing your styled-components package. However, based on an issue linked here, it appears that there is an issue with the styled.div element of styled-components. Check that link out for workarounds for that issue.
Before you begin these workarounds, if you are trying to use the SSR version of styled-components, ensure that

your Astro site has been set up to utilize SSR
you've installed the correct dependencies: styled-components, @swc/core, and @swc/plugin-styled-components

So, once you've done that, I have a possible workaround for you:
Workaround: Add styled-components to Vite config --> Astro Config
In this solution, you will add a "ssr.noExternals = true" to the Vite config, and then add the Vite config to the astro.config.mjs. You will also be sure to correctly import styled-components into the astro.config.mjs by adding it to the vite.plugins list.
./astro.config.mjs:
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

export default defineConfig({
    // vite config object
  vite: {
    plugins: [
        react({
            plugins: [['@swc/plugin-styled-components', {
                displayName: true,
                fileName: true,
                ssr: true,
        }]]
    })],
    ssr: {
      noExternals: true,
    },
});

Then, in your files, import styled-components like this:
import { styled } from @swc/plugin-styled-components

If that doesn't work, try it without the 'ssr.noExternals' option. Then if that still doesn't work, provide some additional context:

astro.config.file
tac-website/src/Headers.js file
package.json file
App.js (or wherever your are loading your main app component!)
the command you run that produces the error (is it npm run build? npm run preview?)
run the command with --verbose flag and then include the contents of that.

In the future, please include as much info as possible as this will help other users be able to better answer your questions!

I tried it with Astro 5 but what I see is Astro using Babel for transpilation and you can config it with SWC
